# unetbootin windows 7 boot-loop

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, unetbootin

I created a windows 7 usb stick with unetbootin on ubuntu. When I restart the computer from usb, I get to a screen with only one option: 'default' and a contdown for 10 seconds.
When I choose this option, nothing happens - exept, the timer restarts at 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use WinUSB, depending on the version of Ubuntu you're running there are different versions of the package.  You'll need to add the correct repository for the version of Ubuntu you are running.  There's a decent article on ask ubuntu [here's the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu)